# Displaying multiple images from imagick results in broken images

Tags: php, image, imagick

I have my imagick/image-creating file working (for the most part), but am running into a problem displaying the images. There are multiple images being generated from the one imagick file, each image being tied to an ID (and each component of the image being defined by the ID). So images are displayed from a URL like so;

```
    http://websiteurl.com/imagick-file/ID
```

When viewing items individually (one at a time) it works just fine, but when I try to load multiple items on one page it results in one or more images "breaking" and not loading. So if I have three images, one of those three may not load, example of image URLS on page:

```
<img src="https://websiteurl.com/imagick-file/1">  
<img src="https://websiteurl.com/imagick-file/2">  
<img src="https://websiteurl.com/imagick-file/3">
```

1 and 2 will load on the page, but 3 does not. I am not sure why only a handful of images break, and it seems to be random, with different images breaking or loading with each reload of the page. Happening regardless of browser or computer.

I would very much appreciate any insight into the problem.

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser's tab and see what's wrong

Comment: Did you get an error message on your log's file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cron and within it create and save these images in the server. Then you could display these images without even calling imagick and therefore these images should be server faster.